# Can't run startup script on Debian VM in Google Cloud - SSH and Serial Console Access Issues

Tags: ssh, debian, google-cloud-platform, systemd, startup-scripts

I've been struggling for days with a SSH access problem on my Compute Engine VM (Debian GNU/Linux 10), with an error in the sshd_config file leading to the inability to restart the SSH service:

```
2024-03-07T19:15:36.885258-03:00 esal-backup-20240307-212226 sshd[560]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 124: Bad configuration option: ServerAliveInterval
2024-03-07T19:15:36.895808-03:00 esal-backup-20240307-212226 sshd[560]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
2024-03-07T19:15:36.949278-03:00 esal-backup-20240307-212226 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
2024-03-07T19:15:36.949532-03:00 esal-backup-20240307-212226 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

In attempting to address this problem, I tried to create a startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo sed -i '124s/^/#/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

However, when I reset the machine, the script doesn't run at all, despite trying everything I can think of. My second approach was to create a user in startup script for Serial Console access:

```
useradd USER
echo USER:PASSWORD | chpasswd
usermod -aG google-sudoers USER
```

Yet again, the startup script fails to execute and the user is not created. The script is in Automation > Startup script. What do I need to do to get this script to work upon machine startup? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create another VM with the same OS/Version. Detach the disk and attach to the new VM as a second disk. Mount the file system and edit the file. Detach and reattach to the original VM and boot. I wrote an article that shows how to recover from similar types of problems with three different methods for Debian: https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/